# Change the way that Dolphin (KDE) mounts a (HFS+) filesystem

Tags: linux, macos, mount, kde, hfs+

Once I click a pendrive formatted with HFS+ filesystem in Dolphin, it mounts it read-only. `dmesg` says:

```
hfsplus: write access to a journaled filesystem is not supported, use the force option at your own risk, mounting read-only.
```

I can mount the fs manually with `force` option all right, but would prefer Dolphin mount it `rw`. Is there a way to change the mount command of Dolphin?